# TypeScript prevent use of Promise, errors on Awaited

Tags: typescript, promise

In the following sample, the I do not want the function `foo` accepting a Promise, but any other type should be OK.

```js
export {}

function foo<T>(arg: T extends Promise<unknown> ? never : T) {
  console.log(arg);
}

async function bar<T>(arg: Promise<T>) {
  foo(await arg); // Why is this an error?
}

async function baz(arg: Promise<number>) {
  foo(await arg); // OK!
}

foo(await Promise.resolve(1)); // OK

foo(1); // OK

foo(Promise.resolve(1)); // Not OK, as intended
```

In the `bar` function, the error is:

```
Argument of type 'Awaited<T>' is not assignable
to parameter of type 'T extends Promise<unknown> ? never : T'.
```

What is the difference between `T` and `Awaited<T>`?

Is there any way to make this work as expected, when using await on a generic?

Comment: You want [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196) and [kigher-kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213): neither exists (yet).

Comment: After messing with this for a bit, I submitted an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49946 I think the compiler should be able to infer that `await arg` does not extend `Promise`.

Answer (score -1):

That type states if `T extends Promise<unknown>` then the argument must be of type `never`. But if we don't know what `T` is inside `bar` then we can not be sure that the type we pass to `foo` is correct.

In other words, it's technically possible to pass a parameter of type `Promise<Promise<any>>` to `bar`, in which case `T` is technically a `Promise`.

However, `await` resolves nested promises, so we know after `await` the resolved value can't be a `Promise`. The Typescript compiler does not seem to be able to pick up on this.

So you can create a generic type for this argument, and safely cast it after `await`.

```js
type NotPromise<T> = T extends Promise<unknown> ? never: T;

function foo<T>(arg: NotPromise<T>) {
  console.log(arg);
}

async function bar<T>(arg: Promise<T>) {
  foo((await arg) as NotPromise<T>);
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-h2izuv?file=index.ts

Comment: One can always just add an explicit type assertion, but that's more of a workaround, I believe.  I'm confused about `Awaited<T>` and how that differs from `T`.  Just because I used await to get it, doesn't make it any different from a plain ol' `T`?

Comment: @Nimai It does behave the same as plain old T, the error still happens in older versions like in that stackblitz. Looks like they introduced it in version 4.5 to help infer more things about the awaited value - it just currently fails this inference.

Comment: If you do `async function bar<T>(arg: T) {foo(arg);}` it fails with the same error for the same reason. This one makes more sense though since `T` can still be a promise.